# how to add object multi NSArray in one NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want add object from 2 NSArray to NSMutableArray. I dont know about this.

this my code:

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *animal;
    NSArray *color;
    NSMutableArray *all;
}


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    animal = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Lion",@"Tiger",@"Dog",@"Cat",@"Sheep",@"Wolf", nil];
    color = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Red",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Black", nil];

    all = ??? ; //how to add object from animal and color array in all 
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use [addObjectsFromArray:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class

```
all = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[all addObjectsFromArray:animal];
[all addObjectsFromArray:color];
```

Comment: there is an error in the initialization, you miss a '[', and you can use `initWithArray` avoiding one instruction

Comment: @duDE : In fact I was sent to human verification also while answering this question. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
animal = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Lion",@"Tiger",@"Dog",@"Cat",@"Sheep",@"Wolf", nil];
color = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Red",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Black", nil];

all = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[all addObjectsFromArray:animal];
[all addObjectsFromArray:color];
```

Comment: I tried with same code.In this case my application getting crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 1):

I am using this:

> ```
> all = @[animal, color];
> ```

But you must convert the array "all" from `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

**all** = [[**all** arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: **animal**] mutableCopy];
**all** = [[**all** arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: **color**] mutableCopy];